# How to say an informal "кроме того"?

Tags: выбор-слова, сленг, синонимы

An acquaintance told me that when I say *кроме того* she think she's hearing the news. Is there an alternative other than  [сверх того](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/en/Translate/en-ru/moreover)? Or is the latter cool enough? I suppose not.

Comment: The most precise and useful answer will depend on what is the situation you use it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most colloquial substitution for `кроме того` meaning 'and also' is `[а] ещё`:

> Я ел пиццу, **кроме того** я пил пиво. = Я ел пиццу, **а ещё** я пил пиво.
>
> Мне нравятся детективы, **кроме того** я люблю фантастику. = Мне нравятся детективы, **ещё** я люблю фантастику.

Also, `[а] ещё` in this meaning can easily be substituted with a mere `и`:

> Я ел пиццу, **кроме того** я пил пиво. = Я ел пиццу **и** пил пиво.

`Кроме того` can also mean 'apart from' in the construction `Кроме того, что … , [так] … .`:

> **Кроме того**, что ты дурак, **[так]** ты ещё и лжец! – Apart from being a fool, you're also a liar!

This can be substituted by the colloquial construction `не только … , но и … .`:

> **Кроме того, что** ты дурак, **[так]** ты ещё и лжец! = Ты **не только** дурак, **но и** лжец!

Comment: `Кроме того, что` as "apart from" sounds strange to me. I'd use `мало того, что` in this situation.

Comment: @YellowSky I think, you can also add "К тому же" to your answer. Sounds rather good to my ear. (also, *lier*→*liar*)

Comment: I think liar is spelt with 'a' not with 'e'. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lier

Comment: @Shady_arc - Do you find "К тому же" colloquial? It sounds rather bookish, as for me. No?

Comment: @YellowSky Not much, nounds neutral to me (I live in Moscow). The corpus suggests that «к тому же» is 2 or three times more popular in writing than in speech, especially if it isn't fiction. However, that might be simply because «к тому же» requires some reasoning, which is more frequent in writing than in the supermarket. I could not compare it against the frequencies of expressions with similar meanings. It seems, however, that is works pretty well in it own niche.

Comment: I mean, I cannot be sure that a situation calling for "besides" happens as often in spoken speech as it happens in an article written beforehand. The different analogues for "кроме того" do not match in their meanings exactly.